# How do i append a simple expression onto IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression

I have the following method:

```
    public List<Customer> SearchTest(string city, int skip, int take)
    {
        EcomContext db = new EcomContext();

        var results = db.Customers.Where(n => n.City == city).OrdeyBy(n => n.Name).Skip(skip).Take(10);

        results = AddDeleteCheck<Customer>(results);

        return results.ToList()
    }
```

And this reusable method:

```
    private IQueryable<T> AddArchivedCheck<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
    {
        var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var e1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Archived"), Expression.Constant(false));
        var e2 = data.Expression;
        var e3 = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(e1, e2), parameter);

        return data.Where(e3);
    }
```

I want to be able to call this method from a number of different functions so i have made it generic.  It should take the expression from the IQueryable object and add a check onto this (Archived == false).

I am getting this error:
The binary operator AndAlso is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean' and 'System.Linq.IQueryable` [Ecom.Customer]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easier than what you wrote:

```
private static IQueryable<T> AddArchivedCheck<T>(IQueryable<T> data)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var e1 = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "Archived"), Expression.Constant(false));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(e1, parameter);
    return data.Where(lambda);
}
```

Remember that in Linq:

```
var result = query.Where(condition1).Where(condition2);
```

is equivalent to:

```
var result = query.Where(condition1 && condition2);
```